# How do I idiomatically compare each item in a list to every other item?

Tags: rust

I have a vec of Points. I wish to calculate the distance between each point. To do this I would traditionally use a nested pair of loops with the inner loop staying one element in front of the outer loop. In this way I compare each pair of points just once.

```
    for i in 0..len {
        for j in i + 1..len {
            // calculate distance between points i and j
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if there is a more idiomatic way to achieve this type of 'triangular' nested loop.

Below is a more complete listing showing the calculation and storage into a `distances` matrix that allows me to access any distance pair.

[Rust Payground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=63e0f28c19dd7f0c7937dbc636500afe)

```
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}
impl Point {
    pub fn rnd(width: i32, height: i32) -> Point {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        Point {
            x: rng.gen_range(0..width),
            y: rng.gen_range(0..height),
        }
    }
}

pub fn get_distances(points: &[Point]) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
    let len = points.len();
    let mut distances: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![0; len]; len];

    for i in 0..len {
        for j in i + 1..len {
            let mut distance =
                (points[i].x - points[j].x).pow(2) + 
                (points[i].y - points[j].y).pow(2);
            distance = (distance as f32).sqrt() as i32;
            distances[i][j] = distance;
            distances[j][i] = distance;
        }
    }
    distances
}

fn main() {
    let points: Vec<Point> = (0..5).map(|_| Point::rnd(400, 600)).collect();
    let distances = get_distances(&points);
    println!("{:#?}", distances);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is some clever iterator trick or something.

Comment: Maybe `Itertools::combinations` (see https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations)?

Comment: @phimuemue It creates a `Vec` for each item, meaning it's probably going to be horribly inefficient.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I've found that reallocating a vector of the same size in a loop is far less inefficient than I would have expected in the past. However, I believe I did the measurements when jemalloc was still the default allocator, so maybe this isn't the case anymore, or it was due to some specifics of my use case at the time. In any case there's also [`tuple_combinations()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_combinations) to avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, maybe `Itertools::tuple_combinations` (https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_combinations) is better there.
Maybe I misinterpreted "idiomatic" as "concise, but possibly not as-efficient-as-possible".

Comment: @phimuemue Generally this is a good idea, but here it needs access to the indices in order to write to `distances` even if it _can_ be written using the iterator, I don't think this will be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage iterators, although the nested for loop it is clear enough:

```rust
pub fn get_distances_iter(points: &[Point]) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
    let len = points.len();
    let mut distances: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![0; len]; len];
    for (i, j) in (0..len)
        .map(|i| (i + 1..len).map(move |j| (i, j)))
        .flatten()
    {
        let mut distance = (points[i].x - points[j].x).pow(2) + (points[i].y - points[j].y).pow(2);
        distance = (distance as f32).sqrt() as i32;
        distances[i][j] = distance;
        distances[j][i] = distance;
    }
    distances
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=30444ecfe8a7229e94777614b333a60a)

Comment: The example you give is very instructive, thank you. Whilst the traditional example is clearer to me, I am still very new to rust so I wonder if a more experienced rust programmer would see your example as equivalently clear and readable?

Comment: @biofractal No. The loop is much clearer.