# Teeing an iterator at every iteration

Tags: rust

I would like to iterate over the Cartesian product of every pair of elements in a list:

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
for i in 0..3 {
    for j in i + 1..4 {
        println!("{} {}", x[i], x[j]);
    }
}
```

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

So far so good. I wanted to attempt the same thing with an iterator. My idea was to grab an iterator for the outer loop, then clone and skip one element for the inner loop. This did not work well:

```
let outer = x.iter();
for pt1 in outer.clone() {
    for pt2 in (&outer).clone().skip(1) {
        println!("{} {}", pt1, pt2);
   }
}
```

Since I had to clone the outer iterator to tee it, the inner is going off the original state, not the current state of the outer iterator:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 2
3 3
3 4
4 2
4 3
4 4
```

**How can I tell rust to replicate the behavior of the range loops with non-consuming iterators over the elements of the collection?**

Related question I found, but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71752804/2988730) still uses iterators over ranges instead of the items themselves: [How do I idiomatically compare each item in a list to every other item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71751384/2988730).

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say that you want to iterate over all the 2-combinations of the elements in a list, i.e. all two element subsets? The Cartesian product would normally mean all possible pairs of elements of the original list without regard to uniqueness and caring about order

Comment: If you only care about generating the result and not the particular implementation of teeing an iterator, there's the existing [`itertools::combinations`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations)/[`itertools::tuple_combinations`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_combinations) mentioned in the comments of the linked question

Comment: I do care about using iterators over the elements. The linked question shows a simple way of doing it with the indices.

Comment: I've updated the question to make that more clear

Comment: Are your iterators `Clone`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman. They certainly appear to be in this case

Comment: Well, I'm asking if you can force them to _always_ be `Clone`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman. For the data I'm working with, that appears to always be the case. Let's say it's always true for the cases I care about.

Answer (score 2):

@brian61354270 already mentioned in the comments, that what you want is not really a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Otherwise an obvious answer would be to use [`itertools::iproduct!`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/macro.iproduct.html).

Going off of your main question:

> I wanted to attempt the same thing with an iterator.

Since we can assume `x: Vec`, and you want to produce indices. Then we can produce a cartesian product of the indices using the range `0..x.len()`.

```rust
let n = x.len();
let indices = (0..n)
    .flat_map(move |x| std::iter::repeat(x).zip(0..n));
```

Now, to get the combinations then we can modify it just slightly (similarly to your `+ i` for loop):

```rust
let n = x.len();
let indices = (0..n)
    .flat_map(move |x| std::iter::repeat(x).zip((x + 1)..n));
```

Then iterating over `indices`:

```rust
for (i0, i1) in indices {
    let (x, y) = (x[i0], x[i1]);
    println!("{x} {y}");
}
```

Will produce:

```
1 2   
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools)'s [`combinations()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations) to achieve the same:

```rust
let indices = (0..n).combinations(2);

for i0i1 in indices {
    let (i0, i1) = (i0i1[0], i0i1[1]);
    let (x, y) = (x[i0], x[i1]);
    println!("{x} {y}");
}
```

---

Since you don't want to map indices to items, then you could do something like this:

```rust
let mut iter = x.iter();
let pairs = std::iter::from_fn(|| {
    let next = iter.next()?;
    let iter = iter.clone();
    Some(std::iter::repeat(next).zip(iter))
})
.flatten();
```

Alternatively, written like this:

```rust
let mut iter = x.iter();
let pairs = std::iter::from_fn(|| {
    iter.next().map(|next| {
        let iter = iter.clone();
        std::iter::repeat(next).zip(iter)
    })
})
.flatten();
```

Where iterating `for (x, y) in pairs` yields the same as before.

*I would however consider both a lot harder to read. At least when compared to using `indices` and then `.map(|(i0, i1)| (x[i0], x[i1]))`.*

Comment: My goal is to iterator over the elements, not the indices. I see that there may have been some miscommunication in my original phrasing, so hopefully the question is clearer now.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The easiest would just be to do `let elements = indices.map(|(i0, i1)| (x[i0], x[i1]))`. Otherwise if it's because you want to use [`slice.iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter), then that's going to be more cumbersome. At that point, it would be easier to just implement a custom iterator and juggle the indices internally. Then implement add utility `.pairs()` methods for slices using a `trait`

Comment: I can clone the iterators in their current state, so clearly this must be possible. I just haven't found the syntax for it.